# Syncfusion Gantt Chart Failed to display in Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, syncfusion

Please if  any familiar with  Syncfusion Gantt Chart in Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET C#.

I used Syncfusion Gantt Chart in Visual Studio 2012 but when I viewing using IE, the Gantt Chart failed to display.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.App_web.WebForm2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.Web, Version=12.3450.0.36, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89" Namespace="Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web" TagPrefix="ej" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <ej:Gantt ID="GanttControlDefault" runat="server" AllowSelection="true" AllowColumnResize="true" 
            TaskIdMapping="Id" TaskNameMapping="Name" ScheduleStartDate="02/23/2014" ScheduleEndDate="03/10/2014"
            StartDateMapping="StartDate" EndDateMapping="EndDate" ProgressMapping="PercentDone" 
            ChildMapping="Children" AllowGanttChartEditing="false" 
            TreeColumnIndex="1">
        </ej:Gantt></asp:Content>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Syncfusion.JavaScript.Web;
using Syncfusion.EJ;
using Syncfusion.Core;
using Syncfusion.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.App_web
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var DataSource = this.GetDataSource();
            this.GanttControlDefault.DataSource = GetDataSource();
            this.GanttControlDefault.DataBind();
        }

        #region Create DataSource for Default Gantt control

        private List<BusinessObject> GetDataSource()
        {
            List<BusinessObject> list = new List<BusinessObject>();

            list.Add(new BusinessObject()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Parent Task 1",
                StartDate = "02/23/2014",
                EndDate = "02/27/2014",
                PercentDone = "40",
                Children = (new List<BusinessObject>()
                    {
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 2,
                            Name = "Child Task 1",
                            StartDate = "02/23/2014",
                            EndDate="02/27/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40",
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 3,
                            Name = "Child Task 2",
                            StartDate = "02/23/2014",
                            EndDate="02/27/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40"                            
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 4,
                            Name = "Child Task 3",
                            StartDate = "02/23/2014",
                            EndDate="02/27/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40"                            
                        }
                    })

            });

            list.Add(new BusinessObject()
            {
                Id = 5,
                Name = "Parent Task 2",
                StartDate = "03/14/2014",
                EndDate = "03/18/2014",
                PercentDone = "40",
                Children = (new List<BusinessObject>()
                    {
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 6,
                            Name = "Child Task 1",
                            StartDate = "03/02/2014",
                            EndDate="03/06/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40",
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 7,
                            Name = "Child Task 2",
                            StartDate = "03/02/2014",
                            EndDate="03/06/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40",
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 8,
                            Name = "Child Task 3",
                            StartDate = "03/02/2014",
                            EndDate="03/06/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40",
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 9,
                            Name = "Child Task 4",
                            StartDate = "03/02/2014",
                            EndDate="03/06/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40",
                        }
                    })

            });
            list.Add(new BusinessObject()
            {
                Id = 10,
                Name = "Parent Task 3",
                StartDate = "03/09/2014",
                EndDate = "03/13/2014",
                PercentDone = "40",

                Children = (new List<BusinessObject>()
                    {
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 11,
                            Name = "Child Task 1",
                            StartDate = "03/9/2014",
                            EndDate="03/13/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40"
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 12,
                            Name = "Child Task 2",
                            StartDate = "03/9/2014",
                            EndDate="03/13/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40",
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 13,
                            Name = "Child Task 3",
                            StartDate = "03/9/2014",
                            EndDate="03/13/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40"
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 14,
                            Name = "Child Task 4",
                            StartDate = "03/9/2014",
                            EndDate="03/13/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40"
                        },
                        new BusinessObject()
                        {
                            Id = 15,
                            Name = "Child Task 5",
                            StartDate = "03/9/2014",
                            EndDate="03/13/2014",
                            PercentDone = "40"
                        }
                    })
            });
            return list;
        }
        #endregion

        #region BusinessObject Creation
        public class BusinessObject
        {
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string EndDate { get; set; }
            public string PercentDone { get; set; }
            public List<object> ResourceID { get; set; }
            public List<BusinessObject> Children { get; set; }
            public string Predescessor { get; set; }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The changes you have done in ASPX and ASPX.CS files for including the control and the datasource are fine ,Can you also please ensure the web.config file with changes for including the necessary Syncfusion dlls ,

```
[web.config]
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
<assemblies>
<add assembly="Syncfusion.EJ.Web, Version= XX.XXXX.X.XX, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89"/>
<add assembly="Syncfusion.EJ, Version= XX.XXXX.X.XX, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3D67ED1F87D44C89"/>
</assemblies>
</compilation>
```

And make sure the following external and internal script files have been referred for rendering the Gantt control

```
<link href="Content/ej/ej.widgets.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/ej/flat-lime/ej.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jsrender.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.easing-1.3.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.globalize.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/ej.web.all.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also please find the online documentation [link](http://help.syncfusion.com/aspnet/getting-started#manual-integration-of-syncfusion-aspnet-controls-into-the-newexisting-application) for creating a ASP.NET C# application with Syncfusion controls .

Thanks